# IIf function inside Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, criteria, jet, iif-function

I have a query and I would like to use an IIf function as part of the criteria.  Here is the full SQL:

```
SELECT Hits.HitID, Hits.ListingID, Hits.HitCount, Hits.HitDate, Hits.HitTypeID, Hits.IsDeleted
FROM Hits
WHERE (((Hits.HitDate)>=[Forms]![frmReports]![txtStartDate]) AND ((Hits.IsDeleted)="N"));
```

Here is the piece of code that causing me anguish:

```
>=[Forms]![frmReports]![txtStartDate]
```

If I have a date on frmReports, this will work fine; however, if no date is entered, this returns 0 records (I want it to return ALL records, if this is the case).

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Hits.HitID, Hits.ListingID, Hits.HitCount, Hits.HitDate, Hits.HitTypeID, Hits.IsDeleted
FROM Hits
WHERE (((Hits.HitDate)>=nz([Forms]![frmReports]![txtStartDate],"1/1/1")) AND ((Hits.IsDeleted)="N"));
```

or this

```
SELECT Hits.HitID, Hits.ListingID, Hits.HitCount, Hits.HitDate, Hits.HitTypeID, Hits.IsDeleted
FROM Hits
WHERE (((Hits.HitDate)>=[Forms]![frmReports]![txtStartDate]) AND ((Hits.IsDeleted)="N"))
    OR (([Forms]![frmReports]![txtStartDate] = "") AND (Hits.IsDeleted="N"));
```

Comment: The second option didn't work, but the first one sure did!  Thank you very much!

Comment: `[Forms]![frmReports]![txtStartDate] = ""` should be replaced with `[Forms]![frmReports]![txtStartDate] Is Null`.